# enumerate with non-standard numbering (1°, 2°, ...)

Tags: symbols, enumerate

How can I get a list environment with numbers 1°, 2°, ...? LaTeX does not accept the symbol `°`.

Answer (score 14):

Try a customization by the [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and the [textcomp](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*\textdegree}]
    \item First
    \item Second
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum:**
With the right input encoding you can also insert `°` directly.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*°}]
    \item First
    \item Second
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although the output will likely pretty pretty similar, I think this is a cleaner version than using `$^\circ$`.

Comment: @doncherry: I first thought about using `\circ` like Werner did. But to me it looked a bit too big as superscript. And with the right input encoding it is even possible to insert `°` directly (see my addendum).

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: Your addendum code does not compile in TeXShop with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaLaTeX engines selected.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Sony: By "does not compile" do you mean there is an error? Or does it just not produce the desired output? You would need an editor that is UTF8-compatible in order to compile the addendum.

Comment: @Werner: I set the encoding to `unicode(utf-8)` and recompiled it. Still does not work.  I get the following error message.  `./differentList.tex:8: String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence
l.8 \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*…}]`

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to obtain this would be to specify your `enumerate` label as `\arabic*$^\circ$` via the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*$^\circ$]
  \item Here is an item
  \item Here is another item
  \item This is the last item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Other alignment options are also available, if needed. A similar output is obtained via the [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate)'s label specification `1$^\circ$`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1$^\circ$]
  \item Here is an item
  \item Here is another item
  \item This is the last item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```